# MySQL Selecting million records to generate urls

Tags: php, mysql

I currently getting a 2 million records from different tables to generate a url to create a sitemap. The script eat too much resources and use 100% of the servers performance

query

```
 SELECT CONCAT("/url/profile/id/",u.id,"/",nickname) as url FROM users AS u
    UNION ALL
    Select CONCAT("url/city/", c.id, "/paramId/",p.id,"/",Replace(p.title, " ", "+"),"/",r.region_Name,"/",c.city_Name) AS url
    From city c 
    Join region r On r.id = c.id_region 
    Join country country On country.id = c.id_country
    cross join param p
    Where country.used = 1
    And p.active = 1
```

//i store it on an array $url_list then process for creating a sitemap..but it takes time and to much resources

//i tried to get the data by batch using `LIMIT 0,50000`
but getting the maxrow for paging takes time. also the code doesn't look good for i have to run a two query that has a large data

```
$url_list = array();


$maxrow = SELECT COUNT(*) AS max from (
 SELECT CONCAT("/url/profile/id/",u.id,"/",nickname) as url FROM users AS u
        UNION ALL
        Select CONCAT("url/city/", c.id, "/paramId/",p.id,"/",Replace(p.title, " ", "+"),"/",r.region_Name,"/",c.city_Name) AS url
        From city c 
        Join region r On r.id = c.id_region 
        Join country country On country.id = c.id_country
        cross join param p
        Where country.used = 1
        And p.active = 1) as tmp

$limit = 50,000;
$bybatch = ceil($maxrow/$limit);
$start = 0;
for($i = 0;$i < $bybatch; $i++){
   // run query and store to $result
       (SELECT CONCAT("/url/profile/id/",u.id,"/",nickname) as url FROM users AS u
        UNION ALL
        Select CONCAT("url/city/", c.id, "/paramId/",p.id,"/",Replace(p.title, " ", "+"),"/",r.region_Name,"/",c.city_Name) AS url
        From city c 
        Join region r On r.id = c.id_region 
        Join country country On country.id = c.id_country
        cross join param p
        Where country.used = 1
        And p.active = 1 LIMIT $start,$limit); 

     $start += $limit;
     //push to $url_list
     $url_list = array_push($result);
}
```

//when finish i use this to create a site map

```
$linkCount = 1;
        $fileNomb = 1;
        $i = 0;
foreach ($url_list as $ul) { 

            $i += 1; 
            if ($linkCount == 1) {
                $doc  = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'utf-8');
                $doc->formatOutput = true;
                $root = $doc->createElementNS('http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9', 'urlset');
                $doc->appendChild($root);
            }


            $url= $doc->createElement("url");
            $loc= $doc->createElement("loc", $ul['url']); 
            $url->appendChild($loc);
            $priority= $doc->createElement("priority",1); 
            $url->appendChild($priority);


            $root->appendChild($url);

            $linkCount += 1;

            if ($linkCount == 49999) { 
                $f = fopen($this->siteMapMulti . $fileNomb .'.xml', "w");
                fwrite($f,$doc->saveXML());
                fclose($f);

                $linkCount = 1;
                $fileNomb += 1;
            }

        }
```

Any better way to do this? or to speed up the performance?

**Added**

Why is this faster than sql query but consumes 1 hundred percent of the servers resources and performance

```
$this->db->query('SELECT c.id, c.city_name, r.region_name, cr.country_name FROM city AS c, region AS r, country AS cr  WHERE r.id = c.id_region AND cr.id = c.id_country AND cr.id IN (SELECT id FROM country WHERE use = 1)');

$arrayCity = $this->db->recordsArray(MYSQL_ASSOC);

 $this->db->query('SELECT id, title FROM param WHERE active = 1');

$arrayParam = $this->db->recordsArray(MYSQL_ASSOC);

foreach ($arrayCity as $city) {
        foreach ($arrayParam as $param) {
          $paramTitle = str_replace(' ', '+', $param['title']);
          $url = 'url/city/'. $city['id'] .'/paramId/'. $param['id'] .'/'. $paramTitle .'/'. $city['region_name'] .'/'. $city['city_name'];
          $this->addChild($url);
        }
}
```

Comment: Well if you are stuck with mysql & php, the best way is simply to queue up task and reduce the limit from 50000 to 10000. Then create a schedule job to work on the task.

Comment: Do you have any indexes on the tables?

Comment: Yup. .it is still very slow, tried also putting it in temp table but creating temptable still slow

Comment: Note that you loop through huge amount of data twice: once that done by ORM `$this->db->recordsArray(MYSQL_ASSOC);` and than by you.
In such situations you better use no ORM and just as i say earlier use  a construction like `while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){ concatenate write to file row-by-row instead collecting data in memory}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you not to use `UNION` and just issue two separated queries. It will speed up a query itself.
Also as you mentioned above it's good idea to get data by batches.

And finally, don't collect all data in memory. Immediately write it to file in your loop.

Just open file in beginning, write each URL entry in loop and close file in end.

— open file for writing

— count query users table

— do several selects with `LIMIT` in loop (as you already done)

— right here in loop `while ($row = mysql_fetch_array())` write each row to file

and than repeat such algorithm for another table.
It would be useful to implement a function for writing data to file, so you can call that function and adhere to the [DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) principle.

Comment: Dealing with that amount of data isn't simple task for DB.
You can try to get fields and concatenate them in PHP. May be it helps.